# Do Function Based on User Select in Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I don't know why, but for some reason I am having a problem running a function based on user selection in HTML Select option...

I can get it to work when just doing one (querySelector), but when I do querySelectorAll and create a for loop, things aren't working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```js
let userLocation = document.querySelectorAll('#userLocation');

for(i=0; i < userLocation.length; i++) {
    userLocation[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(userLocation[i].value === "North Carolina") {
             alert('True');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<section id="users">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Frank</h3>
            <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Dan</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Jimmy</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Bob</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. The closing parenthesis and semicolon (`);`) for the call to `addEventListener` is placed after the closing curly brace (`}`) for your `for` loop instead of after the closing curly brace for your event handler function:

```js
for(i=0; i < userLocation.length; i++) {
    userLocation[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(userLocation[i].value === "North Carolina") {
             alert('True');
        }
    } // <-- ); should be here
}); // <-- ); is here
```

2. The indexing variable in your `for` loop uses the default `var` scope/definition which will cause all listeners to close around the last value (meaning all listeners will use the last listener's `select`'s `value`. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for more. You can fix this by using `let i = 0` instead of just `i = 0`;

Here's your code with those two things fixed:

```js
let userLocation = document.querySelectorAll('#userLocation');

for (let i=0; i < userLocation.length; i++) {
    userLocation[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(userLocation[i].value === "North Carolina") {
             alert('True');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<section id="users">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Frank</h3>
            <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Dan</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Jimmy</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Bob</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select id="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>


</section>
```

---

A couple other things:

1. You should try to avoid duplicate `id` values in the same DOM. While `querySelectorAll('#userLocation')` works, [`id` values should be unique](/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page). You can use a class for the same purpose and classes don't have to be unique.
2. You can avoid the `number`-based loop variable entirely by using [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which allows you to close over the actual element reference instead of an index in the `querySelectorAll` collection.

Here's a sample with both adjustments:

```js
let userLocation = document.querySelectorAll('.userLocation');

userLocation.forEach(l => {
  l.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (l.value === "North Carolina") {
      alert('True');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="users">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Frank</h3>
            <label>Location:</label>
            <select class="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Dan</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select class="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Jimmy</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select class="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="user-box">
            <h3>Bob</h3>
             <label>Location:</label>
            <select class="userLocation">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>


</section>
```